# React + Typescript: Naming a component's property as "type" causes Typescript to throw errror

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am running into an issue where typescript will not allow me to name a property `type`

This fails:

```
import "./styles.css";
import styled from "styled-components";

enum BUTTON_TYPES {
  BUTTON = "button",
  SUBMIT = "submit"
}

interface ButtonProps {
  type: BUTTON_TYPES; // <------------------------ this
}

const Button = styled.button<ButtonProps>``;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button type={BUTTON_TYPES.BUTTON}>hey</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

However, if I rename `type` to `foobar`, it works perfectly fine

```
import "./styles.css";
import styled from "styled-components";

enum BUTTON_TYPES {
  BUTTON = "button",
  SUBMIT = "submit"
}

interface ButtonProps {
  foobar: BUTTON_TYPES; // <------------------------ this
}

const Button = styled.button<ButtonProps>``;

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button foobar={BUTTON_TYPES.BUTTON}>hey</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/charming-borg-hl2x6?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Interesting question. I never tried this since i always wrap HTML elements with my custom component. And i use styled component also, so this behavior is new to me also. Nice catch :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The TS error that you are getting is because of the fact your are trying to override native HTML attribute `type`. This prop is locked to `"button" | "submit" | "reset" | undefined` if you take a look at the type definition.
 This also seems to be a problem with `styled-components` since they break native attributes with matching props.

Aside from the fact that TS prevents you to do this, I think that this way of creating component might be an anti-pattern.

What i would suggest to you, if you want to have `type` with HTML type for `button` element you can do something like this. With this you can forward `type` attribute to be prop your custom `Button` component to others to use:

```js
import React, { FunctionComponent } from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components";

import "./styles.css";

interface ButtonProps{
  type: React.ButtonHTMLAttributes<any>['type'];
}

const ButtonStyled = styled.button`
  color: pink;
`;

const Button : FunctionComponent<ButtonProps>= ({type, children}) => 
  <ButtonStyled type={type}>{children}</ButtonStyled>


export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Button type='button'>hey</Button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Codesanbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/button-type-attribute-m1i3u

**NOTE:**
This may not be what you were looking for, as you want to have enum available to assign to `type` prop, but as i said, i think your way clashes with pattern of wrapping native HTML elements with a custom React component.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a problem with TypeScript. HTML button tag already has a property type that accepts `button`, `reset` or `submit` as a value.

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_button.asp

Comment: Got it. So I can't give it a property of the same name

Comment: Yeah, not if you're using `styled-components`. Their typing logic is not entirely clear for me but it seems like if you try to create a prop with the same name of a prop derived from the React component you're styling it will narrow down to `never`: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/styled-components/index.d.ts#L73